# Function for moving arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am trying to make a function that will move the parts of an array (which is made of widgets) around a circle. It builds and runs but the icons do not appear. Can someone tell me why?

Here is the function in the .cpp file

```
    void setIconWidgetLocation(iconWidget *w, float arcSize)
{
    int outerRadius = 100;
    int innerRadius = 60;
    int radius = (outerRadius + innerRadius)/2;
    arcSize = 2.0 * M_PI/ 5;

    iconWidget *icon[5];

    QSizeF size = w->size();
    QPointF center(size.width(),size.height());
    center /= 2.0;

    //Loop for finding the circles and moving them
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        icon[i] = new iconWidget;

        //Finding the Icon center on the circle
        double x = center.x() + radius * sin(arcSize * i);
        double y = center.y() + radius * cos(arcSize * i);

        x -= 10/2;
        y -= 10/2;

        //moves icons into place
        icon[i]->move(x,y);

    }
}
```

and here is the header file

```
#ifndef ZMENUWIDGET_H
#define ZMENUWIDGET_H
#include "iconwidget.h"

#include <QWidget>

class zMenuWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    iconWidget *icon[5];

public:
    explicit zMenuWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // ZMENUWIDGET_H
```

here is the call of the setIconWidgetLocation.

```
#include "zmenuwidget.h"
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QColor>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <cmath>

setIconWidgetLocation(iconWidget *w, float arcSize);

zMenuWidget::zMenuWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be parenting the icon to your menu when you create it?  And does the icon default to invisible?  You are passing no parameters into the constructor.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by the parameters. they should not be set to invisible. and the icons are children f the menu.

Comment: i am still very new to this

Comment: The thing with programming, and this is even more true when you are new to it, is to build up a program piece by piece.  You need to assure yourself that what you are creating is working at a basic level before you make it more complicated.  To start with, can you write a program that creates and displays a single icon in a widget?  If not, then all other debugging is fruitless.  When you write too much code and then hope for the best, you will set yourself up for a lot of frustration and debugging.

Comment: Originally I had it created and I had brought two "icons" or instances of the iconWidget and manually placed them on the menu. After that I decided that I didn't want to have to hard code every icon and wanted to make a function that would do that for me. In order to do that I thought I had to make an array of "icons" so I could use a loop like you suggested in the previous question I had. I just can't get the icon to show up.

Comment: Show your code that calls `setIconWidgetLocation`

Comment: posted at the bottom of the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22873/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-paddy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually call the function.  What you have shown is a function *declaration* (aka *prototype*).  All it does is tell the compiler that your function exists and states how it is called.

Before I go there, you have a few things to iron out first.  Namely, the parameters don't make sense.  Your function creates and lays out icons for your menu.  So passing in an `iconWidget` is confusing.  Also, you pass `arcSize` but then calculate it inside the function.  I expect that this function should actually be a member of `zMenuWidget`.  Finally, it doesn't just *set* the locations, it also *creates* the icons, so the naming is misleading.

Let's address all these things in one hit:

```
void zMenuWidget::createAndLayoutIcons()
{
    int outerRadius = 100;
    int innerRadius = 60;
    int radius = (outerRadius + innerRadius)/2;
    double arcSize = 2.0 * M_PI/ 5;

    QSizeF size = w->size();
    QPointF center(size.width(),size.height());
    center /= 2.0;

    //Loop for finding the circles and moving them
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        icon[i] = new iconWidget(this);

        //Finding the Icon center on the circle
        double x = center.x() + radius * sin(arcSize * i);
        double y = center.y() + radius * cos(arcSize * i);

        x -= 10/2;
        y -= 10/2;

        //moves icons into place
        icon[i]->move(x,y);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have removed the locally-defined `icon` array from this function, because it's defined in your `zMenuWidget` class.  That's the other hint that you needed to make your function a member of the class.

I also modified the icon creation part to pass the menu widget's pointer to your new icon widget (as its parent).  I assume your iconWidget accepts a parent pointer:

```
        icon[i] = new iconWidget(this);
```

Now in the constructor for `zMenuWidget`, you create your icons:

```
zMenuWidget::zMenuWidget( QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    createAndLayoutIcons(this);
}
```

That should get you moving in the right direction.